# Angularjs service vars in all controller templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'am very new to Angularjs.
I created an Angularjs Service to store some "global" vars. It looks like this:

```
.factory('authVars', function() {
    var sdo = {
        baseBackendUrl: 'https://www.myurl.com',
        user: '',
        password: '',
        token: '',
        isLogged: false
    };
   return sdo;
})
```

Now I want use ng-show/hide in different controllers.

```
<div class="alert" ng-hide="authVars.isLogged">
    <strong>whatEver</strong>
</div>
```

Is this even possible? Or is it better to store this in the rootScope?
For a bit of help I would be very grateful ;-) thx

Comment: thank all of you for the great answers! This helps me out understanding angularjs a bit more :-) Unfortunately I only can accept one answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just register your factory to every controller. This is a goal service for code reuse. Service is like utility, you write it once and can use it in many controllers

**JS**

```
myApp.factory('authVars', function() {
    var sdo = {
        baseBackendUrl: 'https://www.myurl.com',
        user: '',
        password: '',
        token: '',
        isLogged: false
    }; 

    return {
        getSdo: function() {
            return sdo;
        }
    };

})


function MyCtrl($scope, authVars) {

    $scope.authVars = authVars.getSdo();
}
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PxdSP/760/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

It is 100% ok to put it in service! Just don't forget to inject it in **relevant** controllers:

```
var Ctrl = function($scope,authVars){
    $scope.authVars = authVars;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/pzFrs/2/

Answer (score 1):

you need to inject service in controller as below.

```
  app.controller('ctrl',function($scope, authVars){          
    $scope.authVars=authVars;   
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible thanks to the dependency injection system.
You can "inject" this service in every controller where you need it.

Let's say you have a template like that:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <div class="alert" ng-hide="authVars.isLogged">
    <strong>whatEver</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you must have a controller defined like that:

```
.controller('MyController', function (authVars) {
  $scope.authVars = authVars;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to use constans in angular:

Using **angular.constant**

```
angular.module('myApp.config', []).
   constant('APP_NAME', 'MyApp');

angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.config'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'APP_NAME', function($scope, appName) {
     $scope.val = appName;
}]);
```

Using **angular.value**

```
angular.module('myApp.config', []).
   value('config', {
      appName: 'AppName'
   });

angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.config'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'config', function($scope, config) {
     $scope.val = config.appName;
}]);
```

Or the way you did but factory is very often used to setup something once before returning config object eg to $inject some dependencies (like $locale).

Moreover I often use directive **consts** to attach constants in the scope I want to:

```
angular.module('myApp.config', []).

directive('consts', function(config) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function($scope) {
         $scope.config = config;
      }
    }
});
```

And then:

```
<div consts>
  <h2>{{config.appName}}</h2>
</div>
```